# Need to replicate stored procedure changes, but not new columns in SQL Server transactional replication

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, transactional-replication

I have a couple of SQL Server 2016 machines, using transactional replication to replicate a portion of the database to a remote server. It is critical that we control what columns are replicated to prevent accidental exposure of certain data.

We have selected only the appropriate tables, views and columns for replication.  But we found that as new columns were added to these tables/views, they were automatically included in the replication. I was able to disable the replicate schema changes option in the publication. Solved that issue.

This seems to have caused a new issue. We do need to replicate changes made to stored procedures. After disabling replication of schema changes, the data is in sync, but the stored procedures changes are not replicated.

So, any thoughts on how to work around this? Can we default it to not replicate new columns even with replicate schema changes enabled? Or some other way to get it to replicate stored procedures changes without enabling replicate schema changes?

Comment: Give the sprocs their own publication that has schema changes enabled? The only drawback is that statements in different publications are not synchronized, but since you're not replicating schema changes in the tables anyway, that shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: Well, that's not the only drawback of course -- the other is that you have to make sure everybody's subscribed to both publications, which in turn may increase resource usage for replication. But assuming you're scripting these operations (which is a good idea anyway) that should be a minor hurdle.

Comment: @jeroen - a "schema only" publication should have pretty low overhead, no? Might even be able to be at up as a snapshot publication.